# showing map location using latitude and longitude using jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, cordova

I am new to jquery mobile. I have an xml file from which I am parsing latitude and longitude using jquery, and now I want to show the map location using this latitude and longitude. Please help, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is jQuery Google Maps Plugin which provides a simplified JavaScript API to google maps, the Android market link is https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mds.gmapdemo&hl=en

[Click here to getGMap Demo App Source Code](https://github.com/libbybaldwin/GMap-Demo-App)

Comment: The home page for the jQuery Google Maps plugin featured in that app is here (including mobile examples): http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use jQuery Map Plugin ?

http://www.mayzes.org/googlemaps.jquery.html. In the map example, there's longitude, latitude which will suffice i think.

resize your canvas based on your jquery mobile application.